# XML & XSL Programming

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create a link within a table in xml that goes into xsl............

I want the title, description, year, genre, and rating to be links when opening.

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="action.xsl"?>
<!--Lists all horror DVDs-->
<DVDList>
<horrormovie>
<DVDtitle>Title 1</DVDtitle>
<Description>Description 1 </Description>
<Year>Year 1 </Year>
<Genre>Genre 1 </Genre>
<Rating>Rating 1 </Rating>
</horrormovie>
</DVDList>
```

I have tried CDATA and some other things.

Here is my xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<title>Movie Collection!</title>
<body>
<!--Creates table-->
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr bgcolor="#FFA366">
<th>DVD Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Genre</th>
<th>Rating</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="DVDList/horrormovie">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="DVDtitle"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Year"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Genre"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Rating"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
Copyright: &#xa9;2013
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

any help would be appreciated it's driving me crazy.

Comment: just wrap an `a` tag around the `xsl:value-of` elements..  `<a><xsl:value-of select="DVDtitle"/></a>`

Comment: I need it to be in the xml file because I'm going to have more than one title name displayed and I need them all to go to different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xsl:copy-of` and apply it to the child nodes() of your element

```
<xsl:copy-of select="DVDtitle/node()"/>
```

**Demo at** http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/OO7iBG/2